# Recent activity aggregator

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, recent-activity, stackexchange-2.0

Is there any way to view my recent activity for all the StackExchange sites together?

I am aware of a number of previous requests for the recent activity on SU/SF/SO to be combined into one, but I feel that this request is slightly different.

With the large number of StackExchange sites now live, it is becoming increasingly difficult to keep up with my posts on all of them.  I tend to focus on a small number of sites, providing answers where possible on those sites, and simply asking questions on the other sites.  However, unfortunately I do not always remember asking a question on all of these sites.  This is quite a problem, as it means that I can't respond effectively to feedback on those sites.

I'd really love to keep up to date on all those sites, but it just isn't practical to keep checking > 10 sites all day.

What I would like to propose (if such a thing doesn't already exist) is that http://stackexchange.com become a "central place" for all the recent activity indicators if you are logged in.  It would provide a page which would combine the "Recent Activity" pages of all the StackExchange sites into one - a single place to check any recent comments, answers, etc. to questions and answers given on the StackExchange sites.

I am aware that George Edison has created [this application](http://stackcenter.quickmediasolutions.com/display.php) which shows any recent questions, comments, etc. that have been made by any user on all the sites, but it can't show *replies*, etc. to questions and answers.

**EDIT**: This request has been (mostly) fulfilled with the [new global inbox](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/) feature - a slightly different name, and it doesn't show recent edits, etc. but it certainly covers most of my request.

Comment: Duplicate of many other ignored requests for a unified bar, RSS feed, or other similar ways of keeping up with the sites